# How do I get few days back date when I click text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two text boxes for picking dates (to and from). When I click on txtBoxTo calender shows me current date but I need few days back date by default. What property do I use for that? I tried minDate: -30 but not working.

```
$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'DD-MM-yy',
    });
});

 Date From: <asp:TextBox  ID="datepickerFrom" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker" TextMode="DateTime"></asp:TextBox>
        Date To: <asp:TextBox   ID="datepickerTo" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker" TextMode="DateTime"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle or demo we can see?

Comment: ohk mentioning some more details in question

Comment: That is of no help... is your "datepicker" javascript function part of a library or a plugin? Do you have the support pages for the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: -5 });
```

5 day back as default ?

> http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

minDate give something else:

> The minimum selectable date.

Comment: Thanks Phil Andelhofs exactly that i was looking for but i dont know why they gave me -ve for this question,

Comment: Some people dislike questions i guess..Np you can also use -1w for 1 week or, -1y for a year :)